# Rewrite Mod issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the follow code:

```
if (isset($_GET['preis']) && $_GET['preis']==="0-100-euro"){
    $preis = "WHERE preis >= 0 and preis <= 100";
}
elseif (isset($_GET['preis']) && $_GET['preis']==="100-200-euro"){
    $preis = "WHERE preis >= 100 and preis <= 200";
}
elseif (isset($_GET['preis']) && $_GET['preis']==="200-300-euro"){
    $preis = "WHERE preis >= 200 and preis <= 300";
}
elseif (isset($_GET['preis']) && $_GET['preis']==="300-500-euro"){
    $preis = "WHERE preis >= 300 and preis <= 500";
}
else {

}


$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM outfits $preis LIMIT $start, $eintraege_pro_seite";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
```

example.com/?preis=100-200-euro works but example.com/preis-100-200-euro/ is not

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^preis-([^-]*)/seite-([^-]*)/$ ?preis=$1&seite=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^preis-([^-]*)/$ ?preis=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^seite-([^-]*)/$ ?seite=$1 [L]
```

I use the same rules for many other links and it works fine, but only in this case not

Comment: What happens? Do you just get a 404 when you request `/preis-100-200-euro/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're having is that you have dashes in your request but your regular expression explicitly excludes them: `([^-]*)` which means: *zero or more characters that is **not** a dash*.

Try changing your regex to include a dash:

```
RewriteRule ^preis-(.*)/seite-(.*)/$ ?preis=$1&seite=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^preis-(.*)/$ ?preis=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^seite-(.*)/$ ?seite=$1 [L]
```

Or you can change it to exclude slashes:

```
RewriteRule ^preis-([^/]*)/seite-([^/]*)/$ ?preis=$1&seite=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^preis-([^/]*)/$ ?preis=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^seite-([^/]*)/$ ?seite=$1 [L]
```

which may make more sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first element and explode it:
RewriteRule ^preis-([^-]*)/$ ?preis=$1

$preis = $_GET['preis'];
$arrayPreis = explode("-",$preis");

$where = WHERE preis >= $arrayPreis[1] and preis <= $arrayPreis[2]

...
some think like that